# MongoDB Near/GeoNear with the MaxDistance value from Database

Tags: mongodb, gps, erlang, geospatial

I would like to do some quite special using MongoDB, but have yet no idea how to do it.

So here it is :

So far to query a near location, the MaxDistance option is on the query.

I would like to get the MaxDistance from the Object on the database.

To illustrate what I would like, here a little graphic :

- The Black dots are Points on the database
- The Colored circle are the **different** distance from each point
- The Blue dot is the Point from the Query
- In this example, since the Blue dot match 2 circles, thoses 2 (Red and Green) should be returned...

[image: GeoLoc]

While the normal use is looking more this (graphically) :

[image: NormalGeo]

I can't just raise/lessen the BlueDot maxDistance, since it might match (or not) some (BlackDot + their own MaxDistance) when it should not.

I'm using Erlang, by the way...

Any idea, how I can do that without having to retrieve ALL Points from database and do the GPS math inside my software ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently it can be done using aggregation : found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15536064/mongodb-near-geonear-query-with-variable-distance)

```
pipeline : [
  {
    '$geoNear' : {
      near : [
        10, 
        10
      ],
      distanceField : 'distance',
      spherical : false,
      uniqueDocs : true
    }
  }, 
  {
    '$project' : {
      name : 1,
      location : 1,
      maximumDistance : 1,
      delta : {
        '$subtract' : [
          '$maximumDistance', 
          '$distance'
        ]
      }
    }
  }, 
  {
    '$match' : {
      delta : { '$gte' : 0 }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: This answer is gold! Thx a lot

Comment: @TheSquad Could you please tell me whose maximum distance does the field "maximumDistance" in the $subtract refer to ? Is it of the current user's max distance or that of other user's max distance ?