# How to get the records which contains the given location in its radius? Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, geospatial

My DB Mongoose schema looks like this.

```
var blogSchema = mongoose.Schema({
blogText: { type: String},
location: {type: [Number]},
radius : {type: Number},
});
blogSchema.index({location: 2dsphere});
 ... .. .. ...
```

Sample data looks like below

```
{ 
"_id" : 58ef3f1919f99e3bb37ce21b, 
"location" : [
    77.706106, 
    12.9447252
], 
"radius" : "4000",
"blogText" : "News 1 ....."},
{ 
"_id" : 58ef3f19b37ce21b19f99e3b, 
"location" : [
    77.709979, 
    12.9703882
], 
"radius" : "1000",
"blogText" : "Health 1 ....."},
{ 
"_id" : 58ef3f1919f99e3bb37ce21b, 
"location" :[
    77.7060119, 
    12.9488936
], 
"radius" : "3500",
"blogText" : "Lifestyle 1 ....."},
{ 
"_id" : 58ef3f1919f99e3bb37ce21b', 
"location" :  [
    77.709979, 
    12.9703882
], 
"radius" : "100",
"blogText" : "Sports....."},
{ 
"_id" : 58ef3f1919f99e3bb37ce21b', 
"location" : [
    77.706106, 
    12.9447252
], 
"radius" : "800",
"blogText" : "Tech ....."}
```

I have to fetch only those blogs which contains the user location under the blog location and radius.

My query looks like. Which  fetch the data based on the location and radius of the request.

```
db.blogs.find({location: {$geoNear: {$geometry: {type: "Point",coordinates: [77.706106,12.9447252]}$maxDistance: 500,$minDistance: 0}}}} })
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified from this so [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15536064/mongodb-near-geonear-query-with-variable-distance), this might work for you.

Use aggregate to push documents through a pipeline with three stages.

1) `$geoNear`: find all documents near your desired coordinates, and return a generated `distanceField` called `distance`.

2) `$project`: Use the `$distance` found in stage 1 and subtract from `$radius`, store as delta.

3) `$match`: Filter out all delta less than or equal to zero.

```
db.blogs.aggregate([
  {
    '$geoNear' : {
      near : [77.706106,12.9447252],
      distanceField : 'distance',
      includeLocs: 'location',
      spherical : true
    }
  }, 
  {
    '$project' : {
      name : 1,
      location : 1,
      delta : {
        '$subtract' : [
          '$radius', 
          '$distance'
        ]
      }
    }
  }, 
  {
    '$match' : {
      delta : { '$gte' : 0 }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: You are right, I incorrectly changed the name of a field. It is fixed above.

Comment: now cannot  $subtract a numberdouble from a string.

Comment: I didn't realize you were storing radius as a string. There may be a way to project that as well but best practice would be to store radius as an int or float.

Comment: I am storing it as number you can see the schema radius : {type: Number}

Comment: I don't know about mongoose orm, but if your example data is correct then your radius is being stored as a string.

Comment: @ismail, what are you getting at?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141681/discussion-between-ismail-and-phillip-martin).